# Is it natural to use the plural form of tea?

Tags: plural-forms, countability

According to Oxford Dictionary, tea is uncountable. However, there's a countable form i.e. a cup of **tea**. Is it natural to leave out *a cup of* and just say *two teas please*, for example?

I saw a sentence that used plural teas from Du*lingo:

> **These teas, do you want them?**

Is that sentence OK grammatically?

Comment: 'Two teas please, Louise' is a UK catch-phrase, and the song of pigeons, doves, etc has been likened to it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can "staff" ever be pluralized?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/167896/can-staff-ever-be-pluralized)

Comment: You can also use **tea** as a countable noun meaning "variety or flavor of tea" as in, "this tea shop has more **teas** than I could have imagined."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's perfectly grammatical since the context is clear.

When you encounter the question of countable versus uncountable, it's useful to think in terms of the substance (uncountable) versus a specific variety or quantity of the substance (countable).
Consider:

> Tea is good for you (uncountable - referring to the substance)

> A tea in the morning is a great way to start your day (countable - referring to a serving/quantity of the substance i.e. a (cup of) tea

This is quite common for food/drinks. (Beer, wine, steak - there are a lot)

Remember, where the context is clear (i.e. ordering food/drink), the countable form without the specific serving vessel or quantity is often used:

> Two beers, please

> A water with ice, please

Answer (score 2):

These phrases: "**n** teas", "**n** beers" are short forms of "**n** cups of tea", "**n** bottles of beers" respectively.

It might be well understood when you say that. When you want to write it as such, it is incorrect (at least grammatically).

Comment: This! if the sentence used implies a specific number of servings of an uncountable substance, this technically is not completely correct grammar, but verbal language often takes shortcuts with grammar for quicker communication.

Answer (score 2):

This use is normal in British English. I believe it is much less common in American English.

Lynne Murphy says in *The Prodigal Tongue*, chapter 6:

> [Something else] echoes the established British hot-drink patterm.
> Americans meet other Americans ***for coffee***. If they want to count
> how many coffees, they generally add a countable noun, like *cup*: *two
> cups of coffee*. Brits might meet ***for a coffee***.